# On isospectral planar domains (and a paper by Buser, Conway, Doyle and Semmler)

Tags: gr.group-theory, sp.spectral-theory, manifolds, euclidean-geometry, isospectrality

I have never seen a short, elegant way (from the viewpoint of a non-topologist) which constructs isospectral planar domains from Sunada group triples, although essentially those triples live at the very origins of the first constructions of such pairs. In a paper by Buser, Conway, Doyle and Semmler, the authors try to easily describe such examples in the orbifold language, and here is an example.

> [image]

I find the second paragraph pretty unclear, and especially the fact that those quotients are planar (the most important feature), is too vague for me, and just too short.

My question(s):

(1) can anyone explain this second paragraph in clear terms to me, knowing that I am not a topologist ?;

(2) is there a more elegant ("direct") way to pass from the isospectral hyperbolic examples, to the plane ?

Comment: For reference, [here](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~doyle/docs/drum/drum.pdf) is a link to the paper hosted by Peter Doyle.

Comment: recommend Conway's little book, The Sensual Quadratic Form from about the same time, and usually downloadable after search. The big book, SPLAG, will have more